# How to create a "Slither" action in a SpriteKit Snake game?

Tags: swift, animation, sprite-kit, skaction

I am trying to make a Snake game in SpriteKit. I thought this would be super easy to do, while utilising all of SpriteKit's `SKAction` features such as timing modes, sequences, groups, etc. However, I found myself creating a lot of custom actions and it felt very unnecessary. Here are the basics; it seems like a lot of code but it's super easy to understand:

### The Basics

```swift
class SOSnake: SKNode {
    let size: Double  // A snake is a bunch of squares. Thus size represents an individual square's length
    var body: [SOBodyPart]  // All the body parts will be stored here so we can interate over them
    
    init(ofSize size: Double) {
        self.size = size
        self.body = [SOBodyPart(type: .head, size: size)]
        super.init()
        addChild(head)
    }
    
    var head: SOBodyPart { body.first! }  // for convenience
    var tail: SOBodyPart { body.last! }  // for convenience. When body.count == 1, head === tail
}
```

```swift
// In my actual game, there is a `type` property which is either "head", "body", or "tail". 
// This determines the colour of the SKSpriteNode.
// This isn't relevant for the problem so I omitted it. 
class SOBodyPart: SKSpriteNode {
    init(id: Int, size: Double) {  // id is used for its name
        super.init(texture: nil, color: .yellow, size: CGSizeMake(size, size))
        self.name = String(id)
    }
}
```

### My implementation of a slither function

Finally, I created a method called `move()`. This function returns an `SKAction`, which when run on the Snake node, will cause each body part to move in the direction it's facing. Here is its simple implementation:

```swift
// Since each body part's name is `id`, I can use String(indexInBodyArray) to reference it
func move() -> SKAction {
    let actions = body.indices.map { SKAction.run(.move(Direction.of(body[$0]), by: size, duration: 1), onChildWithName: String($0)) }
    return SKAction.group(actions)
}
```

##### Helpers

*(Can be skipped. Only posted for context)*

```swift
enum Direction {
    case up, down, left, right
    
    static func of(_ node: SKNode) -> Direction {
        // if node.zRotation is within 0º - 45º ... 0º + 45º it'll return `right`
        // if node.zRotation is within 90º - 45º ... 90º + 45º it'll return `up`
        // and so on...
    }
}

extension SKAction {
    static func move(_ direction: Direction, by amount: Double, duration: TimeInterval) -> SKAction {
        switch direction {
        case .up:
            return .move(by: .init(dx: 0, dy: amount), duration: duration)
        case .down:
            return .move(by: .init(dx: 0, dy: -amount), duration: duration)
        case .left:
            return .move(by: .init(dx: -amount, dy: 0), duration: duration)
        case .right:
            return .move(by: .init(dx: amount, dy: 0), duration: duration)
        }
    }
}
```

### The Problem

The problem comes when I try calling the move function from my SKScene:

```swift
private func onTap() {
    let action = snake.move()
    action.duration = 10.0
    action.timingMode = .easeInEaseOut
    snake.run(action)
}
```

The changes I make to `action` **are not reflected when the action is run**. This is because `run(_:onChildWithName:)` is executed instantaneously. Thus, in my game, I was forced to create custom actions using `customAction(withDuration:actionBlock:)` in order to utilise all of SpriteKit's action customisations.

This felt very strange as I'm writing code for things that already exist in SpriteKit, namely translating/moving a node. Is there any built-in way to implement the `move()` function such that changes made to the returned `SKAction` reflect when it's run? Or are custom actions the only way to achieve what I'm trying to achieve?

Please let me know what's the simplest way to implement a `move()` function while still being able to utilise things such as timing modes, sequences, etc.

Comment: yes, once you call SKAction.group(...) or SKAction.run(...) those will get baked in. you can't modify them any more. solution is to change move() to return a *dictionary* of move_actions + SOBodyParts. then onTap() can still cycle through the dictionary and modify each move_action accordingly. also you didn't ask, but you will have *much* more success modeling a slithering snake using SKPhysicsBody ;)

Comment: Maybe another interesting approach instead of custom actions can be use SKPhysicsJoint for different sections of the snake